# How can I fix react-redux resolve problem?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I recently study about redux.

I install redux below

```
npm install -save redux @types/react-redux
```

I keep try to fix this problem...
but is not working

This is my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/react": "16.14.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.10",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.14",
    "firebase": "8.2.0",
    "node-sass": "4.14.1",
    "query-string": "6.13.7",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

error

```
./src/index.tsx
Modules not found : Can't resolve 'react-redux' ...
```

and this is my index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import rootReducer from './testsrc/modules';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import CounterContainer from './testsrc/container/CounterContainer';


const store = createStore(rootReducer);


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <CounterContainer/>
  </Provider>,
  
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to install `redux` and `react-redux` by running the command

```
  npm install --save redux @types/redux
```

and

```
npm install --save react-redux @types/react-redux
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! but i use typescript 
Does it have anything to do with using typescript?? and i fix it!

Comment: @조성현 check this out now. changed for typescript

Answer (score 0):

you need to install `react-redux` too.
using this code:

```
npm install react-redux
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies doesn't contain a `react-redux`, therefore your system doesn't see that as installed.

Try:

```
npm install react-redux
```